# How to group by a column of list

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have an imaginary movie dataframe. I would like to group Sales by the values in the list of the Genre column. How can I do it (preferably without exploding the Genre column)? For example, the total sales by genre.

Thanks

```
data = {
  "Movie": ["Avatar", "Leap Year", "Life is Beautiful","Roman Holiday"],
  "Sales": [5000, 2500, 2800, 4050],
  "Genre": [["Sci-fi","Action"], ["Romantic", "Comedy"], ["Tragic", "Comdey"], ["Romantic"]]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
sales_by_genre = df.groupby(df['Genre'].map(tuple))['Sales'].sum() # <<< This line not working
```

Comment: What's wrong with exploding the Genre column?

Comment: `<<< This line not working` why? and what is the error?

Comment: Code Different, nothing much. Even though exploding and then grouping by the exploded column values will give the right answer, the newly inserted rows due to explosion appear to give a distorted and inflated sales.

I know this is not logically coherent. I just want to explore if there are other ways to do this.

Comment: SomeDude, there is no error generated. The resulting dataframe is "unexploded" and almost unchanged. List is now tuple and number of rows remain unchanged with no aggregation happening.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a straight forward way of doing this without exploding the list, so here is an example with `explode`:

```
df = df.explode(column='Genre', ignore_index=True)[['Sales','Genre']].groupby('Genre').sum()
print(df)
```

result:

```
          Sales
Genre          
Action     5000
Comdey     2800
Comedy     2500
Romantic   6550
Sci-fi     5000
Tragic     2800
```

Comment: Ok, thanks.
Is there a reason why ```df.explode(column='Genre', ignore_index=True)``` is wrapped with an extra pair of parentheses?

Comment: Not really, sorry that was a left over from a previous try :)